# c++ std::thread join() after thread is out of scope

Tags: c++, multithreading, macos, cocoa, thread-safety

my first attempt at a real question in here.  I've searched around, but haven't gotten a good answer to come up, so apologies if this is a LMGTFY question.

I am working on a runtime loop for a c++ application engine.  It's a standard run loop, that I want to execute on it's own thread, so I can control the execution timing without relying on OS specific dependencies.  However, I want to still have the app window play nice with os, in this case Mac OSX, so I have an objective-C platform object that passes key/mouse input to my application.  My intent is to have the engine collect input through atomic arrays, and then the app can appropriately respond to Cocoa callbacks from the OS, but I can still retain control over the game loop.

**The problem I'm running into** is that my current setup involves a method for starting the thread, and a separate thread for joining the thread so Darwin can be happy with how the threads all terminate.

```
//This is all in a class named engine.
id thread; // What type?
bool engineRunning;

int Engine::startYourEngines() {
        engineRunning = true;
        std::thread thread (engineLoop()); //How do I keep this thread?
        
    }

    int Engine::stopYourEngines() {
        engineRunning = false;
        thread.join(); //Thread is out of scope...or is it?
        return 0;
    }
    
    int Engine::engineLoop() { //Only invoke this with Engine::startYourEngines()
        engineThread = std::this_thread::get_id();
        
        do {
            // do things here!
            }
        } while (engineRunning);
        
        return 0;
    } /* Engine::engineLoop() */
```

All of the examples I find use a single function for launching the thread and joining it.  I don't want to detach the thread because that's just a can of worms.  It seems like getting the thread ID is a way to identify the thread, but then I don't know how to use the ID to find the thread again.  That seems to be the most straightforward way to do what I want to do.

Comment: What "object" is responsible for `join`ing on the thread? RAII suggests this should be the same object that launches the thread. You have the `Engine` object, it seems reasonable that `Engine` contains the `thread` object (or a list of `thread` objects if you have multiple you need to `join` on).

Comment: Would you ever create an `Engine` and not want to launch a `thread` within it? Does `Engine` ever do any useful work when the worker `thread` is not running (either before or after its launch)?

Comment: The reason I am going the thread route is because I am creating it within applicationDidFinishLaunching, and if the loop runs from that thread, mac OSX thinks the app is frozen.  Right now my only way to handle user input is to have the engine respond to the calls that macOS sends it.

the engine launches the thread in the "startYourEngines()" call.  The "stopYourEngines" joins the thread.  I would be glad to stick the thread in as a private member of engine, but I don't know how to do that, and can't find an answer online.

Comment: I think the thread route is fine. I use this idiom a lot in my multithreading work (usually asynchronous IO, which keyboard input falls under). I'm just curious if you have a use case for creating an `Engine` without creating the underlying `thread`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to have an object `Engine` launch a worker `thread`, and hold the reference to that context so it can be neatly closed when its time to shutdown. If you're working with C++20 you'd use `jthread`s and `stop_token`s for super neat RAII. If you're not using 20 (which is likely), then you have to roll your own.

I will call this the stop token idiom since that's what the C++20 concept is called. (I assume) you want to do the following:

- Create a neat `Engine` class that handles input and output to the worker thread.
- On `Engine` creation, open your worker thread, and
- keep it running until `Engine` destruction.

If you *must* use an init-type method (`startYourEngines`) and a teardown-type method (`stopYourEngines`), then a possible solution would look like this.

```
// each start requires a paired stop
// may not double-start or double-stop
// starting and stopping are not thread-safe (may not run at the same time in different threads)
class Engine {
public:
    Engine() : run_engine_{false}, worker_{} {}

    void startYourEngines() {
        run_engine_ = true; // tell the engine it's okay to run
        worker_ = std::thread([&]{ engineLoop(); }); // start running the engine
    }

    void stopYourEngines() { // changed return type to void since you're not returning anything
        run_engine_ = false; // tell the engine to stop running
        worker_.join(); // wait for engine to stop running
    }

    void engineLoop() { // changed return type to void since you're not returning anything
        while (run_engine_) {
            // do things here!
        }
    }
};
```

In the above, each `startYourEngines` call must be paired with a `stopYourEngines` call. You may not double-start or double stop your engines, and you may not call `startYourEngines` and `stopYourEngines` concurrently. There are ways to allow start and stop calls from different threads, but it's easier to just forbid the developer from doing this.

I personally find the "init" and "teardown" style functions odious. Since your code ends up looking like

```
Engine engine;
engine.startYourEngines();
...do program stuff here until ready to shutdown...
engine.stopYourEngines();
```

A neater alternative is to incorporate RAII-style code, where constructing an `Engine` creates the thread of execution, and deconstructing an `Engine` tears it down. But the above should be enough to get you going.

Comment: Thanks! this is super helpful!  Your question about c++20 was correct, I think I have to stay on C++11...since it's Apple...and they "swiftly" put a smackdown on that...After a little thought, it would be easier to have construction launch the thread, and then have it start in a paused state, then I could switch a flag to essentially start execution of the object.  Is there a good resource for the RAII way to incorporate a thread in an object?

Comment: RAII is a terrible acronym that just means any resource owned by an object is created in the constructor and destroyed in the destructor. So any user of the class doesn't have to worry about additional setup details. You'd pretty much move the init stuff to the constructor and the deinit stuff to the deconstructor.

Answer (score 0):

After a day of hacking around, here's what I came up with as a workable solution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

class Engine {
public:
    bool engineRunning = true;
    void engineLoop() {
        do {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
            std::cout << "engine running\n";
        } while (engineRunning);
    }
    std::thread engineThread;
    Engine() {
        engineThread = std::thread(&Engine::engineLoop, this);
    }
    ~Engine() {
        engineRunning = false;
        if (engineThread.joinable()) engineThread.join();
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::cout << "start program\n";
    Engine *testThread = new Engine;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    std::cout << "kill engine \n";
    testThread->engineRunning = false;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
    std::cout << "Done!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for the comments and help!  Feel free to comment on the code above! I always want to get better!

Comment: You should make `engineRunning`, `engineThread`, and `engineLoop()` each `private`. These are implementation details and should remain under the hood. Someone may end up depending on these variables/functions existing. Then in `Engine` version 2.0 when you remove these (maybe you implement it some better way) it breaks their code.

Comment: You also have a memory leak in `Engine* testThread = new Engine;`. Each `new` requires a complementary `delete` in order to free the allocated memory. Normally on small programs this doesn't practically matter because the OS cleans up any dangling memory. But in your case it actually DOES matter since you're relying on you `Engine` going out of scope to call the destructor. Here, it's never called.

Comment: You don't even need to dynamically allocate a `new Engine`. You can achieve this same thing and have object destruction (which is desired) by typing `Engine testThread;`. That will default create a new `Engine` object, and then at the end of the object's scope (end of `main()`), the object will be destroyed, and will be cleaned up automatically. No need to call `testThread->engineRunning = false;`

Comment: The destructor `~Engine` of an object is called automatically (the compiler inserts this function call for you) when an object goes out of scope. Automatic management of object scope is a key feature of C++ that you're not taking advantage of here because you're *dynamically allocating* the object. You should *automatically allocate*, which again is accomplished by `Engine testThread;` instead of `Engine* testThread = new Engine;`.

Comment: Thanks much!  I agree, private would be better.  And yes, I am still very new to the heap, so this is helpful to get some pointers (get it) to use moving forward.  It does make me wonder if I could keep the engine class running in the main function, and somehow pass it over to the NSApplication class...But I know this is getting out of scope here.  I'll ponder it as I develop!

Comment: "It does make me wonder if I could keep the engine class running in the main function, and somehow pass it over to the NSApplication class." this is a question of ownership. Whenever these come up, I go back to my trusty notebook and draw boxes and arrows. I figure out which objects own which data. That informs whether something is a member variable of another class, whether it holds a reference to something else, or when to use dreaded global variables (usually never).

Comment: Well, to update, I got the thread running fine, and had to scrap it when trying to tie it to the MacOS application object.  Apparently any drawing or such must be called by the main thread.  But this was a great exercise of thought, and now I really have a good handle of the do{}while engineLoop concept.  It just doesn't work in Objective C.  So I whipped up a NSTimer and reworked the engine class to respond to an "update" method.  But now I'm interested in what others do to port a run loop between mac OS and other platforms.  I'll post another question soon.